# How to search for files in a record on python?

Tags: python

I am writing a program where students are written onto a file and can be search when inputted their specific data. However I am not sure if the search_record method in my script is right. It can sometimes return the right results but also on other times when inputted different data it doesn't work.

TA = Teacher advisor

Here is my current program:

```
def read_record():
    in_file = open("student.txt", "r")

    stud_num = in_file.readline()

    while stud_num != "":
        last_name = in_file.readline
        first_name = in_file.readline
        TA = in_file.readline()

        stud_num = stud_num.rstrip("\n")
        last_name = last_name.rstrip("\n")
        first_name = first_name.rstrip("\n")
        TA = TA.rstrip("\n")

        print "Student number: ", stud_num
        print "Last name: ", last_name
        print "First name: ", first_name
        print "TA: ", TA
        print

        stud_num = in_file.readline()

    in_file.close()



def write_record():
    num_students = input("Enter number of students: ")

    out_file = open("student.txt" , "w")

    for counter in range (1, num_students + 1):
        stud_num = raw_input("Enter student number: ")
        last_name = raw_input("Enter last name: ")
        first_name = raw_input("Enter first name: ")
        TA = raw_input("Enter TA: ")

        out_file.write(stud_num +"\n")
        out_file.write(last_name +"\n")
        out_file.write(first_name +"\n")
        out_file.write(TA + "\n")

    out_file.close()

def menu():
    print "STUDENT MENU"
    print "============="
    print "A. Create student file"
    print "B. Display student file"
    print "C. Add student file"
    print "D. Search records"
    print
    choice = raw_input("Enter your choice: ")

    return choice

def add_record():
    out_file = open("student.txt", "a")

    another = "Y"

    while another == "Y":
        stud_num = raw_input("Enter student number: ")
        last_name = raw_input("Enter last name: ")
        first_name = raw_input("Enter first name: ")
        TA = raw_input("Enter TA: ")
        print

        out_file.write(stud_num + "\n")
        out_file.write(last_name + "\n")
        out_file.write(first_name + "\n")
        out_file.write(TA + "\n")

        another = raw_input("Do you want to enter another student (Y or N): ")

    out_file.close()

def search_record():
    in_file = open("student.txt", "r")

    found = False

    print "RECORD MENU"
    print "============="
    print "A. Search student number"
    print "B. Search student last name"
    print "C. Search student name"
    print "D. Search student TA"
    print

    choice = raw_input("Enter your choice: ")

    if choice == "A":
        search = raw_input("Enter a student number: ")
        stud_num = in_file.readline()

        while stud_num != "":
            last_name = in_file.readline()
            first_name = in_file.readline()
            TA = in_file.readline()

            stud_num = stud_num.rstrip("\n")
            last_name = last_name.rstrip("\n")
            first_name = first_name.rstrip("\n")
            TA = TA.rstrip("\n")

            if search == stud_num:
                print "Student number: ", stud_num
                print "Last name: ", last_name
                print "First name: ", first_name
                print "TA: ", TA
                print
                found = True

            stud_num = in_file.readline()


    elif choice == "B":
        search = raw_input("Enter a student last name: ")
        last_name = in_file.readline(2)

        while last_name != "":
            stud_num = in_file.readline()
            first_name = in_file.readline()
            TA = in_file.readline()


            stud_num = stud_num.rstrip("\n")
            last_name = last_name.rstrip("\n")
            first_name = first_name.rstrip("\n")
            TA = TA.rstrip("\n")

            if search == last_name:
                print "Student number: ", stud_num
                print "Last name: ", last_name
                print "First name: ", first_name
                print "TA: ", TA
                print
                found = True

            last_name = in_file.readline()

    elif choice == "C":
        search = raw_input("Enter a student name: ")
        first_name = in_file.readline(3)

        while first_name != "":
            stud_num = in_file.readline()
            last_name = in_file.readline()
            TA = in_file.readline()           

            stud_num = stud_num.rstrip("\n")
            last_name = last_name.rstrip("\n")
            first_name = first_name.rstrip("\n")
            TA = TA.rstrip("\n")

            first_name = in_file.readline()

            if search == first_name:
                print "Student number: ", stud_num
                print "Last name: ", last_name
                print "First name: ", first_name
                print "TA: ", TA
                print
                found = True
            first_name = in_file.readline()


    elif choice == "D":
        search = raw_input("Enter a TA: ")
        TA = in_file.readline(4)

        while TA != "":
            stud_num = in_file.readline()
            last_name = in_file.readline()
            first_name = in_file.readline()


            stud_num = stud_num.rstrip("\n")
            last_name = last_name.rstrip("\n")
            first_name = first_name.rstrip("\n")
            TA = TA.rstrip("\n")

            if search == TA:
                print "Student number: ", stud_num
                print "Last name: ", last_name
                print "First name: ", first_name
                print "TA: ", TA
                print
                found = True

            TA = in_file.readline()


    else:
        print "Invalid entry"


    in_file.close()

    if not found:
        print "Student record not found"


def main():
    choice = menu()

    if choice == "A":
        write_record()
    elif choice == "B":
        read_record()
    elif choice == "C":
        add_record
    elif choice == "D":
        search_record()
    else:
        print "error"


main()
```

the student file I have created to test is

```
12345
Potter
Harry
Wong
6789
Turner
Timmy
Mack
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a DB. Have you used SQL lite? It would be great for this.

Comment: You have put a lot of work into your program but your question is too vague.  You probably need to provide some examples and also try to focus the question where you think the unexpected results are coming from.  I don't want to read this line by line to sort out the issues.

Comment: *"(...) sometimes return the right results but also on other times when inputted different data it doesn't work."* Seeing examples of "the right result" and "it doesn't work" would be helpful

Comment: Besides providing some test cases that do and don't work, we're going to also need the `student.txt` data file (or a subset of it to use when running the code).

Comment: For example when I put in student number it works for all of them. It also works all for the first person but when it gets to the second, the results change. For example when I put the name Timmy in, it just returns student record not found. When I search for the TA Mack, it just returns that name with the rest of the data being empty.

Comment: It is the search_record() function that is causing me some trouble.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all I want to mention that you have a lot of cut and pasted code.

Then to make your search function work.
You need to have virtually the same code running as when you search for student number..the only difference is you're asking a different prompt like for choice B Search by student last name to ask for a last name instead of student number.
and instead of comparing `search == stud_num:`
you compare `search == last_name:`...that should be the only difference.
How you loop through and reading the data should be identical to when user enter choice A...

But it's not working because you're trying to read last_name first and also you're calling readline() but with a number which specifies number of bytes to read.  that's why it's failing.